# A simple way to solve a system of three equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

I would like to find a simple way to solve the system:

$mv=(m+M)v_1,\ \ \ \ \qquad(1)$

$2mv=(2m+M)v_2,\qquad(2)$

$3mv=(3m+M)v_3.\qquad(3)$

It will be nice to know some trick (of course, if it exists) to express $v_3=v_3(v_1,v_2)$ easy. The answer is:

$v_3=\dfrac{3v_1v_2}{4v_1-v_2}$.

**My attempt:**

All variables are positive: $m,M,v,v_1,v_2,v_3>0.$

Dividing (3) by (2) we obtain:

$\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{3m+M}{2m+M}\dfrac{v_3}{v_2},$

and from here we get:

$v_3=\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{2m+M}{3m+M}v_2.\ \ \ \qquad(4)$

Also, dividing (2) by (1) we have:

$2=\dfrac{2m+M}{m+M}\dfrac{v_2}{v_1},$

and from here we obtain:

$2mv_2+Mv_2=2mv_1+2Mv_1,$

and from here:

$m=\dfrac{M(2v_1-v_2)}{2(v_2-v_1)}.$

Let's substitute this expression for $m$ into (4), we get:

$v_3=\dfrac{3}{2}v_2\dfrac{\dfrac{M(2v_1-v_2)}{v_2-v_1}+M}{\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{M(2v_1-v_2)}{v_2-v_1}+M}=\dfrac{3}{2}v_2\dfrac{2v_1-v_2+v_2-v_1}{\dfrac{3}{2}(2v_1-v_2)+v_2-v_1}=\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{v_1v_2}{2v_1-\dfrac{1}{2}v_2}=\dfrac{3v_1v_2}{4v_1-v_2}.$

So, the answer is:

$v_3=\dfrac{3v_1v_2}{4v_1-v_2}.$

And I am interested if there is an easier way to get this result for $v_3$.

Comment: Please show your attempts. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: That system is not linear.

Comment: The answer is not correct - consider, say, $m=1$ and $M=-3$. Then your formula gives $v_3=\frac{0}{0}$, which is not defined.

Comment: Where do $m,M,v$ live? They could be for instance the indeterminates of a polynomial ring like $\Bbb Z[m,M,v]$. And the solutions $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ (of the *linear* system) could then belong to the field $\Bbb Q(m,M,v)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval, thanks and sorry please, Now I've done this.

Comment: @jjagmath, thanks, you are right. I am sorry and now I have changed the title of my question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks, your counterexample is really true. I am sorry, now I have added a condition, that all variables of the system are positive.

Comment: @AnneBauval, $m,M,v$ and also $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are positive. Sorry, now I have added this condition into my question (as well as my attempt). Thank you again.

Comment: Why do I feel $m,M,v$ are the masses of secondary & primary objects in orbit, and the revolutional speed respectively?

Comment: @EtackSxchange, this is a physics problem on one-dimensional motion and the law of conservation of momentum. Three runners of equal mass $m$ jump into an initially stationary shopping cart of mass $M$, and $v_3$  is the final speed of the cart when all three runners are in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting
$$x:=\frac v{v_1},\;y:=\frac v{v_2},\;z:=\frac v{v_3},\;t:=\frac Mm,$$
the system becomes
$$x=1+t,\;y=1+\frac t2,\;z=1+\frac t3$$
hence
$$z=ax+(1-a)y$$
where $a$ is determined by $a+\frac{1-a}2=\frac13,$ i.e. $a=-\frac13.$ As a result,
$$z=\frac{4y-x}3,$$
i.e.
$$v_3=\frac{3v_1v_2}{4v_1-v_2}.$$

Comment: If $a=-\frac{1}{3}$ then why did you write $z$ with respect to $a$ first?

Comment: I solved $1+\frac t3=a(1+t)+(1-a)\left(1+\frac t2\right)$ for $a$ and found $a=-\frac13.$ @EtackSxchange

Comment: @AnneBauval, thanks. I've understood. Could you tell please how did you know that we can write $z=ax+(1-a)y$ and then find $a$ from here? We can write $z=ax+by$, but how did you know that b=$1-a$? Or you just found this through calculations?

Comment: I noticed the $1$ in each of $z,x,y$, which made me immediately find $b=1-a.$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thanks! I understood. It follows from $1=a\cdot1+b\cdot1$.